# Limit contration rates and expansion rate solenoid map

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, fractional-calculus, hyperbolic-dynamics

Let M:=$S^{1}\times \mathcal{D}^1$ where $\mathcal{D}=\{v\in \mathcal{R}^2 | |v|<1\}$ carries the product distance and suppose $f:M\rightarrow M$,$(x,y,z)\rightarrow (\gamma x, \lambda y+v(x), \mu z +u(x))$ is a $C^{2}$map where $\gamma ,\lambda$ and $\mu:M\rightarrow \mathcal{R}^{+}$,
$\gamma >1>\lambda>\mu$.

**Question**

For T=$\gamma ,\lambda$,$\mu$,let $T_{n}(p):=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}T(f^{-i})$.

What should be $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\lambda_{n}(p)+\mu_{n}(p)}{\gamma_{n}(p)}$?

comment:

I think since we have $\gamma >1>\lambda>\mu$ so we have $\gamma^{-1} <1<\lambda^{-1}<\mu^{-1}$.then $\lambda^{-1}+\mu^{-1}>\gamma^{-1}$.But i am not sure, we can talk higher iteration.